# When getting "Premature end of script headers" in Apache error log, is it possible to also log the GET arguments sent to the script?

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, mod-fcgid

I have a single PHP script on a fairly high traffic server that is throwing off a lot of errors of this sort:

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
Premature end of script headers: script.php
```

However, for any parameters I can think of, the script returns successfully and immediately.  There have also been no user complaints, nor any corresponding errors in the PHP error log.

However, it's only this one script that is giving any errors, so I assume there must be a problem causing it to fail under certain conditions.  In order to debug further, I need to know what GET parameters are being sent to the script when it fails.  Is there a way to modify Apache's error logging to include this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in a somewhat cludgy way by grepping the domain access log for the IP address from the error in the error log.  That let me narrow down to the specific request that was failing.  Was able to get the arguments from the access log that way, as well as confirm that it's returning internal server error (500).